# Cognito Events: Sync Triggers not firing

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have created a lambda that should be triggered whenever a cognito user does a sync on my application.

I have checked in the console, under the lambda section that it has indeed a sync trigger set to that identity pool.

I have also performed a simple test in that lambda to make sure it adds logs to Cloud Watch. Which it does (It fails because it does not have the cognito information when triggering it, but that was expected)

I have checked in the console, under federated identities that it has indeed a cognito event sync trigger pointing to the correct lambda.

In my application (Unity application) I create a new cognito user and do a sync, I receive the sync success callback.

The logs don't get updated, which means the event is not firing when I sync.

I have looked around the internet a lot about this, but all I can find are old topics about it that are not relevant to my situation. Has anyone successfully got this working? I could use some help on why it's not firing the event.

Cheers,
Cai